# small vs smaller. Which one is correct?

Tags: comparative-constructions

- Women’s feet are usually smaller than men’s.

Shouldn't it be small instead of smaller? Can you please explain me the reason behind this?

Comment: Why do you think it should be *small* rather than *smaller*?

Comment: It is looking fine to me; I don't know why. :(

Answer (score 2):

Small :  Being below the average in size or magnitude. (adj)

Smaller : Small or relatively small to something else (adj)

from the freedictionary.com

Smaller is usually used when you are comparing A to B, in your sentence smaller would fit perfectly because you are comparing women's feet to men's feet so you would say "Women's feet are usually *smaller* than men's"

Comment: So, it is correct? 1) Your score is lesser than my score. 2) You are taller than me.

Comment: 1)Your score is lower than my score

Comment: Isn't this incorrect? Shouldn't it be like this: Your score is lower than mine's score.

Comment: You will not use lesser,but you will use 'lower' instead, because in your example, were talking about my score and your score, and since you have a higher score than I do, you should say "Your score is lower" , also lower refers to being below a certain rank or position

Comment: No it should be " Your score is lower than my score"

Comment: Why can't I say lesser? secondly, Which one is correct? I am taller than you OR I am taller than you are.

Comment: @hellodear2: we do encounter "lesser" for comparing scores but it does not sound appropriate. We encounter it in video games and such that are made by people whose English is not standard English.

Comment: @hellodear2: You cannot say "*mine's score". "Mine" already expresses "possession", and we do not use genitive after a possessive pronoun.

Comment: @hellodear2: both are correct "I am taller than you" and "I am taller than you are". In the fist sentence "are" is implicit (we know it's there even if we don't write/say it).

Comment: @hellodear Might be worth asking a new question for "mine's score" if you're still unclear about it - you might get a fuller answer if you need one. (Not that there's anything wrong with your answer Laure.)

Comment: I want you to feel safe here. OR I want you to feel safer here. Which is correct now?

Comment: Both can be correct. I want you to feel safer means you are comparing with another time, place, or situation, eg "I want you to feel safer than you did when you lived in the city". "smaller", "safer" etc, are called comparatives. You might like to do a search for this. This site gives a basic introduction: http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives.

Comment: Just like Laure said, I agree with her

Answer (score 0):

As for your other question, "I want to feel safe/safer here"

They are both correct, but the first one is more general " Just feel safe"

The second one, on the other hand, is like you want to be  more safe.

I hope that makes it clear to you.